# NUMA 1 not used on SQL Server 2008 R2 on Windows Server 2008 R2 on ESXi

Tags: windows-server-2008, sql-server, virtualization, vmware-esxi, numa

We've got Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2 running on Windows Server 2008 R2, virtualized on VMWare ESXi 6.7.0.

The server has 2 CPU sockets with 22 cores each.
The VM is allocated 8 sockets with 3 cores each and 64 GB RAM (ServerEnterprise).

Inside the VM i see two NUMA nodes, each with 11 CPUs.

Unfortunately, SQL server uses only the CPUS on NUMA Node 0 and NUMA Node 1 is idling.

What am i doing wrong? Am i limited by licensing or misconfiguration?

[image: Resource monitor screenshot]

Comment: 2008 R2 is at end of support, and there are only a couple years left of extended security updates.  https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/sql-server/end-of-support/sql-server-end-of-life-overview    Probably upgrading will have better NUMA behavior, but that is not your biggest problem, staying supported is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering myself the document the solution.

SQL Server 2008 R2 Standard is licensed for 4 sockets or 24 cores, whichever is **less**. With my case, with 8 sockets, only 4 of them were used.

Switching the VM to 4 sockets, 6 cores each allows us full utilization of the resources.